# msyql regexp hide uppercase words

Tags: mysql

I want to use regexp to hide all results starting ONLY with capital A-Z

This query hiding all the uppercase and lowercase words
SELECT coupon_id, name FROM ocl_coupon WHERE name NOT REGEXP '^[A-Z]'

is there any solution to hide only the uppercase words?

Answer (score 2):

The default collation is case-insensitive.

```
mysql> select 'Athon' not regexp '^[A-Z]' as `match`;
+-------+
| match |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+

mysql> select 'athon' not regexp '^[A-Z]' as `match`;
+-------+
| match |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+
```

But you can change the collation of an expression:

```
mysql> select 'Athon' collate utf8mb4_0900_as_cs not regexp '^[A-Z]' as `match`;
+-------+
| match |
+-------+
|     0 |
+-------+

mysql> select 'athon' collate utf8mb4_0900_as_cs not regexp '^[A-Z]' as `match`;
+-------+
| match |
+-------+
|     1 |
+-------+
```

Collations whose names end with "cs" are case-sensitive.

Refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/case-sensitivity.html